# weblogic data source not listed in eclipse

Tags: eclipse, jsf, netbeans

I was developing java ee applications in netbeans, for some reason I jumped to eclipse.

In netbeans when I click on "entity classes from database" I used to see oracle's data source, basically the database. And easily I used to create my beans.

Now, is there any way to do so in eclipse? If so, how to do that?

Answer (score 2):

There is no direct equivalent for the netbeans functionality you are seeking in eclipse (or at least not that I know of in the stock eclipse install).

For starters, you should be using the eclipse version built for **Java EE developers**. It has a Data source explorer as one of the tabs. Here, you can add data sources that you can use to configure your applications.

More information [here](http://www.cleartoolkit.com/dokuwiki/doku.php?id=clearwiki:20.cleardatabuilder:02.creating_cdb_project:02.building_workspace_datasource).